# Creating Seperate Context for Each GPU while having one display monitor

Tags: opengl, glx

I want to create one GL Context for each GPU on Linux using the GLX. As [nVIDIA Slides](http://on-demand.gputechconf.com/gtc/2012/presentations/S0353-Programming-Multi-GPUs-for-Scalable-Rendering.pdf) show, it is pretty simple and I just have to use ":0.0" for the first gpu and ":0.1" for the second one in  `XOpenDisplay` function. I have tried it but it only works with ":0.0" but not with ":0.1". I have two gpus: GTX 980 and GTX 970. Also, as the `xorg.conf` shows the `Xinerama` is disabled. Furthermore, I only have one display monitor and it is connected to the GTX 980.

Do you have any idea about how to fix that? or what is missing?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <X11/Xlib.h>
#include <X11/Xutil.h>
#include <GL/gl.h>
#include <GL/glx.h>

#define GLX_CONTEXT_MAJOR_VERSION_ARB       0x2091
#define GLX_CONTEXT_MINOR_VERSION_ARB       0x2092
typedef GLXContext (*glXCreateContextAttribsARBProc)(Display*, GLXFBConfig, GLXContext, Bool, const int*);

// Helper to check for extension string presence.  Adapted from:
//   http://www.opengl.org/resources/features/OGLextensions/
static bool isExtensionSupported(const char *extList, const char *extension)
{
  const char *start;
  const char *where, *terminator;

  /* Extension names should not have spaces. */
  where = strchr(extension, ' ');
  if (where || *extension == '\0')
    return false;

  /* It takes a bit of care to be fool-proof about parsing the
     OpenGL extensions string. Don't be fooled by sub-strings,
     etc. */
  for (start=extList;;) {
    where = strstr(start, extension);

    if (!where)
      break;

    terminator = where + strlen(extension);

    if ( where == start || *(where - 1) == ' ' )
      if ( *terminator == ' ' || *terminator == '\0' )
        return true;

    start = terminator;
  }

  return false;
}

static bool ctxErrorOccurred = false;
static int ctxErrorHandler( Display *dpy, XErrorEvent *ev )
{
    ctxErrorOccurred = true;
    return 0;
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
  Display *display = XOpenDisplay(":0.1");

  if (!display)
  {
    printf("Failed to open X display\n");
    exit(1);
  }

  // Get a matching FB config
  static int visual_attribs[] =
    {
      GLX_X_RENDERABLE    , True,
      GLX_DRAWABLE_TYPE   , GLX_WINDOW_BIT,
      GLX_RENDER_TYPE     , GLX_RGBA_BIT,
      GLX_X_VISUAL_TYPE   , GLX_TRUE_COLOR,
      GLX_RED_SIZE        , 8,
      GLX_GREEN_SIZE      , 8,
      GLX_BLUE_SIZE       , 8,
      GLX_ALPHA_SIZE      , 8,
      GLX_DEPTH_SIZE      , 24,
      GLX_STENCIL_SIZE    , 8,
      GLX_DOUBLEBUFFER    , True,
      //GLX_SAMPLE_BUFFERS  , 1,
      //GLX_SAMPLES         , 4,
      None
    };

  int glx_major, glx_minor;

  // FBConfigs were added in GLX version 1.3.
  if ( !glXQueryVersion( display, &glx_major, &glx_minor ) ||
       ( ( glx_major == 1 ) && ( glx_minor < 3 ) ) || ( glx_major < 1 ) )
  {
    printf("Invalid GLX version");
    exit(1);
  }

  printf( "Getting matching framebuffer configs\n" );
  int fbcount;
  GLXFBConfig* fbc = glXChooseFBConfig(display, DefaultScreen(display), visual_attribs, &fbcount);
  if (!fbc)
  {
    printf( "Failed to retrieve a framebuffer config\n" );
    exit(1);
  }
  printf( "Found %d matching FB configs.\n", fbcount );

  // Pick the FB config/visual with the most samples per pixel
  printf( "Getting XVisualInfos\n" );
  int best_fbc = -1, worst_fbc = -1, best_num_samp = -1, worst_num_samp = 999;

  int i;
  for (i=0; i<fbcount; ++i)
  {
    XVisualInfo *vi = glXGetVisualFromFBConfig( display, fbc[i] );
    if ( vi )
    {
      int samp_buf, samples;
      glXGetFBConfigAttrib( display, fbc[i], GLX_SAMPLE_BUFFERS, &samp_buf );
      glXGetFBConfigAttrib( display, fbc[i], GLX_SAMPLES       , &samples  );

      printf( "  Matching fbconfig %d, visual ID 0x%2x: SAMPLE_BUFFERS = %d,"
              " SAMPLES = %d\n",
              i, vi -> visualid, samp_buf, samples );

      if ( best_fbc < 0 || samp_buf && samples > best_num_samp )
        best_fbc = i, best_num_samp = samples;
      if ( worst_fbc < 0 || !samp_buf || samples < worst_num_samp )
        worst_fbc = i, worst_num_samp = samples;
    }
    XFree( vi );
  }

  GLXFBConfig bestFbc = fbc[ best_fbc ];

  // Be sure to free the FBConfig list allocated by glXChooseFBConfig()
  XFree( fbc );

  // Get a visual
  XVisualInfo *vi = glXGetVisualFromFBConfig( display, bestFbc );
  printf( "Chosen visual ID = 0x%x\n", vi->visualid );

  printf( "Creating colormap\n" );
  XSetWindowAttributes swa;
  Colormap cmap;
  swa.colormap = cmap = XCreateColormap( display,
                                         RootWindow( display, vi->screen ),
                                         vi->visual, AllocNone );
  swa.background_pixmap = None ;
  swa.border_pixel      = 0;
  swa.event_mask        = StructureNotifyMask;

  printf( "Creating window\n" );
  Window win = XCreateWindow( display, RootWindow( display, vi->screen ),
                              0, 0, 100, 100, 0, vi->depth, InputOutput,
                              vi->visual,
                              CWBorderPixel|CWColormap|CWEventMask, &swa );
  if ( !win )
  {
    printf( "Failed to create window.\n" );
    exit(1);
  }

  // Done with the visual info data
  XFree( vi );

  XStoreName( display, win, "GL 3.0 Window" );

  printf( "Mapping window\n" );
  XMapWindow( display, win );

  // Get the default screen's GLX extension list
  const char *glxExts = glXQueryExtensionsString( display,
                                                  DefaultScreen( display ) );

  // NOTE: It is not necessary to create or make current to a context before
  // calling glXGetProcAddressARB
  glXCreateContextAttribsARBProc glXCreateContextAttribsARB = 0;
  glXCreateContextAttribsARB = (glXCreateContextAttribsARBProc)
           glXGetProcAddressARB( (const GLubyte *) "glXCreateContextAttribsARB" );

  GLXContext ctx = 0;

  // Install an X error handler so the application won't exit if GL 3.0
  // context allocation fails.
  //
  // Note this error handler is global.  All display connections in all threads
  // of a process use the same error handler, so be sure to guard against other
  // threads issuing X commands while this code is running.
  ctxErrorOccurred = false;
  int (*oldHandler)(Display*, XErrorEvent*) =
      XSetErrorHandler(&ctxErrorHandler);

  // Check for the GLX_ARB_create_context extension string and the function.
  // If either is not present, use GLX 1.3 context creation method.
  if ( !isExtensionSupported( glxExts, "GLX_ARB_create_context" ) ||
       !glXCreateContextAttribsARB )
  {
    printf( "glXCreateContextAttribsARB() not found"
            " ... using old-style GLX context\n" );
    ctx = glXCreateNewContext( display, bestFbc, GLX_RGBA_TYPE, 0, True );
  }

  // If it does, try to get a GL 3.0 context!
  else
  {
    int context_attribs[] =
      {
        GLX_CONTEXT_MAJOR_VERSION_ARB, 3,
        GLX_CONTEXT_MINOR_VERSION_ARB, 0,
        //GLX_CONTEXT_FLAGS_ARB        , GLX_CONTEXT_FORWARD_COMPATIBLE_BIT_ARB,
        None
      };

    printf( "Creating context\n" );
    ctx = glXCreateContextAttribsARB( display, bestFbc, 0,
                                      True, context_attribs );

    // Sync to ensure any errors generated are processed.
    XSync( display, False );
    if ( !ctxErrorOccurred && ctx )
      printf( "Created GL 3.0 context\n" );
    else
    {
      // Couldn't create GL 3.0 context.  Fall back to old-style 2.x context.
      // When a context version below 3.0 is requested, implementations will
      // return the newest context version compatible with OpenGL versions less
      // than version 3.0.
      // GLX_CONTEXT_MAJOR_VERSION_ARB = 1
      context_attribs[1] = 1;
      // GLX_CONTEXT_MINOR_VERSION_ARB = 0
      context_attribs[3] = 0;

      ctxErrorOccurred = false;

      printf( "Failed to create GL 3.0 context"
              " ... using old-style GLX context\n" );
      ctx = glXCreateContextAttribsARB( display, bestFbc, 0,
                                        True, context_attribs );
    }
  }

  // Sync to ensure any errors generated are processed.
  XSync( display, False );

  // Restore the original error handler
  XSetErrorHandler( oldHandler );

  if ( ctxErrorOccurred || !ctx )
  {
    printf( "Failed to create an OpenGL context\n" );
    exit(1);
  }

  // Verifying that context is a direct context
  if ( ! glXIsDirect ( display, ctx ) )
  {
    printf( "Indirect GLX rendering context obtained\n" );
  }
  else
  {
    printf( "Direct GLX rendering context obtained\n" );
  }

  printf( "Making context current\n" );
  glXMakeCurrent( display, win, ctx );

  glClearColor( 0, 0.5, 1, 1 );
  glClear( GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT );
  glXSwapBuffers ( display, win );

  sleep( 1 );

  glClearColor ( 1, 0.5, 0, 1 );
  glClear ( GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT );
  glXSwapBuffers ( display, win );

  sleep( 1 );

  glXMakeCurrent( display, 0, 0 );
  glXDestroyContext( display, ctx );

  XDestroyWindow( display, win );
  XFreeColormap( display, cmap );
  XCloseDisplay( display );

  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason it works with ":0.0" but not with ":0.1" is because they are the X display and screen numbers. ":0.0" means the first screen on the first display and ":0.1" means the second screen on the first display.

These numbers are for selecting which monitor you wish to display the window to and not which GPU you wish to use. As you have only one monitor attached you only have one screen so ":0.1" fails.

I believe the slides expect you to have two or more monitors attached, each driven by a different GPU.